# How do I validate a UUID with Symfony Validator?

Tags: validation, symfony, uuid

I don't understand how to use Symfony Validator to validate a UUID.
The documentation is pretty poor and I can't find any concrete example around.
My goal is pretty simple: I have a UUID, I want to check if it's valid, I want to do stuff if so or not.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your class add the annotation `Uuid`.

[From the doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Uuid.html),

```
// src/AppBundle/Entity/File.php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class File
{
    /**
     * @Assert\Uuid
     */
     protected $identifier;
}
```

From there it's like any other validation constraint.

To use it outside a class, you can use the [Validator component](http://symfony.com/doc/2.7/components/validator.html):

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints\Uuid as UuidConstraint;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation;
//...

public function myFunction()
{
    //...

    $validator = Validation::createValidator();

    $uuidContraint = new UuidConstraint();
    $uuidContraint->message = 'Your customized error message';

    $errors = $validator->validate(
        $uuidToValidate,
        $uuidContraint
    );

    if (0 !== count($errors))
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: But my UUID doesn't belong to a class. I get my string in a request, I want to validate it. I cannot use annotations either because of code style.

Comment: Bam! Altough on Symfony3 the method is "validate" instead of "validateValue". Thanks a lot!